# Capture the FTP log when downloading a file in R

Tags: r, ftp

I want to download a file via ftp, and also capture the ftp log. I managed to get this far:

```
options(internet.info = 0)  # displays the ftp log in the console

x <- capture.output(
  download.file("ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/1KB.zip", destfile = tempfile()),
  type = "message"
)
```

This displays the ftp log in the console and captures some `download.file()` output to the variable `x`, but it does not capture the ftp log. I also tried some fiddling around with `sink()`, but no success.

Can anyone explain to me why this is not working, and is there any way to achieve what I want? I want to process some ftp messages so simply getting back an error code would not suffice.

Comment: Are you using Linux or have access to a similar shell such as Git Bash?

Comment: I asked your question to the author of the `curl` package and there [is a way](https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues/120#issuecomment-330580210) to get debug info from the connection. However, your zip file is quite unusual in structure, which is causing some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of sebastian-c and the original package author I was able to devise a solution for my problem with the [curl](https://github.com/jeroen/curl) package. I'll try to preserve it here for posterity:

```
curl_download_with_log <- function(
  url,
  destfile
){
  log <- rawConnection(raw(), 'r+')
  on.exit(close(log))
  stopifnot(is.character(url))

  h <- curl::new_handle(
    debugfunction = function(type, data){
      if(type %in% c(0, 1, 2)){ 
        writeBin(data, log)
      }
    },
    verbose = TRUE
  )

  try({
    curl::curl_download(url, destfile = destfile, handle = h)
  })

  rawToChar(rawConnectionValue(log))
}
```

This function will save the file to `destfile`, and return the log as a character vector.

Explaination:

- `debugfunction` tells libcurl what to do with the debugging data. In this case, write it to a binary connection
- `if(type %in% c(0, 1, 2)){...}` ensures that only log data is written to the debug connection. If you leave this out, the whole file you download gets written to the debug log along with the protocol data (see [link](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html) for explaination of the different debug levels)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linux or Cygwin or Git bash, you can pipe the results of a script to a text file. If you put your code (without the output capturing) into a file called `script.R` you can pipe all the output to a text file:

```
Rscript script.R &> script.txt
```

You can do something like this within R - but it feels evil to me:

```
uri <- "ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/1KB.zip"
destination <- tempfile()

system2("Rscript", 
        c("-e", 
          sprintf("\"options(internet.info = 0);download.file('%s', destfile = '%s', quiet = FALSE)\"", 
                  uri, 
                  destination)), 
        stderr = TRUE, stdout = TRUE)
```

Comment: I want to wrap the download in a function an process (potential) error codes, so that solution does not help me :/

Comment: Ah, pity. I've had a problem like this before and it's not trivial to get those messages. Have you considered using another package like `curl` to download the file? There may be better error handling there.

Comment: I tried curl, but also couldn't find a way to do it (which does not mean that it doesn't exist).